# How to combine these tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

In sql server 2005, how do I get the result set in table3 below?  table3 is created by combining table1 and table2 like this:

table1.empid
   table1.ticket
   table2.identid

And update against table1 joined to table2 doesn't work because empid isn't unique.  If need to increment to the next table2.indentid if the ID is already being used by that employee.

Also, table3 below isn't created yet. It's a generated set from table1 and table2.  I'm using table3 as an example of what the generated set should look like.

```
table1
empid   ticketid   indentid
1       7          20
1       9          4
2       9          21

table2
indentid   empid
90         1
91         1
92         2

table3 
empid   ticketid  table1_indentid    table2_identid
1       7         20                 90
1       9         4                  91
2       9         21                 92
```

Comment: Just a comment and opinion.  From what I read it sounds more like a poor data modeling issue and not a query issue.   Perhaps you should consider revising your data model.

Comment: your question is very hard to understand.  Are you trying to create 'table3' as output of a query of table1 and table2?  You are having trouble with inserts?

Comment: I'm just trying to create the data shown in table3 from table1 and table2.  The problem is empid is not unique.  When I do an update/join of table1 and table2, I get table2_identid=90 twice.  So in my table3 above, I don't have 91.  I have 90 there.

Comment: I agree with @John Hartstock - this is a normalization issue.  as it is, you have no way to link the records as you have shown them - for instance: how do you know ident_id 90 goes with ticket 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only connection between table1 and table2 is `empid`.
The lines 1 and 2 of your table3 example have the same empid, so they should have the same table2_identid as well. Your example is not proper, or not possible to get with a query on the existing data.

---

But maybe this is what you want:
If you join the tables like so

```
SELECT empid, ticketid, t1.indentid as table1_indentid, t2.identid as table2_identid
FROM table1 AS t1
    INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.empid = t2.empid
```

you will get

```
table3 
empid   ticketid  table1_indentid    table2_identid
1       7         20                 90
1       7         20                 91
1       9         4                  90
1       9         4                  91
2       9         21                 92
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
select t1.empid, t1.ticketid, 
       t1.indentid as table1_indentid, 
       t2.indentid as table2_identid
from table1 t1 
inner join table2 t2 on t1.empid = t2.empid
```

You should however consider reviewing your data structure.

Comment: table3 isn't created yet.  It's a set generated from table1 and table2.  I've revised the question.